# Date string conversion doesn't return decimal miliseconds Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, nsdateformatter

I need to check if a date string is of this exact format 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 with 3 decimal milliseconds, otherwise return.

I'm using `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS` but this doesn't return any decimal milliseconds. Why is that? When I convert `Date()` to string with `DateFormatter`, then it returns correct `ss.SSS`.

```
let str = "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") as TimeZone!
if let date = df.date(from: str) {
    print("date: \(date)")
} else {
    print("no")
}

output: date: 2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

More, there is no error if I add ss.S/ss.SS all return true. why?

Comment: The default description for a `Date` value does not print out the milliseconds but it's there. What is your question?

Comment: I need to check if a date string is of this exact format 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 with 3 decimal milliseconds, otherwise return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [date formatter patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) says that `1...n` digits for the milliseconds is valid. You can write as many capital `S` as you want - it makes no difference. You have to check for the second condition separately:

```
extension String {
    var endsWithThreeDecimalDigits: Bool {
        return self.range(of: "\\.\\d{3}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
df.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")

if let date = df.date(from: str), str.endsWithThreeDecimalDigits {
    print("date: \(date)")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why milliseconds are missing in the output date? output: date: 2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: I don't see the point of this `endsWithThreeDecimalDigits` check. If the `if let date = df.date(from: str)` part of the code succeeds, then you already know the string ended with three digits because if it didn't, the string doesn't match the date format and `df.date(from: str)` would return `nil`.

Comment: @JimH. as I explain earlier, the millisecond is there. Apple chose to not show it when you call `print` since few applications require that level of precision. As you've discovered, it shows up when you call `df.string(from: date)`

Comment: @rmaddy `2017-01-01 00:00:00.12345` is a valid date according to the formatter but does not meet the OP's requirement of "exactly 3 decimals for the milliseconds"

Comment: @CodeDifferent Strange. I didn't expect that but sure enough it does. So this answer should be what the OP wants.

Comment: @CodeDifferent that explains everything. I was just wondering why decimal points were missing

Comment: @maddy in that case yes if let should be enough

Comment: @CodeDifferent Why parsing `7-1-1 00:00:00.123` succeeds when given format is clearly `yyyy-MM-dd` ?

Comment: @JimH. that you have to ask Apple. It works out to Jan 1, year 7 AD